# How to use vanilla JS with React component (zoom to bounds on load react mapbox gl)

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl

I am looking to be able to zoom to bounds when my component mounts.

I know this vanilla JS code can achieve the zoom to bounds, but not sure how to massage this into the React code below (I think a need a REF?):

```
var bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds();

parkDate.features.forEach(function(feature) { 
    bounds.extend(feature.geometry.coordinates);
});

map.fitBounds(bounds, {
    padding: {top: 20, bottom:20, left: 20, right: 20}
})
```

**Component:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactMapGL, { Marker } from "react-map-gl";
import * as parkDate from "./data.json";
const mapIcon: any = require('../images/mapIcon.png');

export default function App() {

  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: 45.4211,
    longitude: -75.6903,
    width: "100%",
    height: "400px",
    zoom: 10
  });
  const [selectedPark, setSelectedPark] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactMapGL
        {...viewport}
        mapboxApiAccessToken="pk.eyJ1IjoiYmVubmtpbmd5IiwiYSI6ImNrY2ozMnJ5dzBrZ28ycnA1b2Vqb2I0bXgifQ.ZOaVtzsDQOrAovh9Orh13Q"
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
        onViewportChange={viewport => {
          setViewport(viewport);
        }}
      >
        {parkDate.features.map(park => (
          <Marker
            key={park.properties.PARK_ID}
            latitude={park.geometry.coordinates[1]}
            longitude={park.geometry.coordinates[0]}
          >
            <button
              className="marker-btn"
              onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                setSelectedPark(park);
              }}
            >
              <img src={mapIcon} alt="Map Pointer Icon" />
            </button>
          </Marker>
        ))}
      </ReactMapGL>
      {selectedPark ? (
        <div>
          <h2>{selectedPark.properties.NAME}</h2>
          <p>{selectedPark.properties.DESCRIPTIO}</p>
          <button onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                setSelectedPark(null);
              }}>X</button>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have rolled this question back to an earlier version, as it has been changed to read like an answer. We need questions to be preserved as questions here, so the answers still make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactMapGL, { Marker, WebMercatorViewport } from "react-map-gl";
import * as parkData from "./data.json";
const mapIcon: any = require('../images/mapIcon.png');

const applyToArray = (func, array) => func.apply(Math, array)

const getBoundsForPoints = (points) => {
  console.log('Points:', points)
  // Calculate corner values of bounds
  const pointsLong = points.map(point => point.geometry.coordinates[0])
  const pointsLat = points.map(point => point.geometry.coordinates[1])
  const cornersLongLat = [
    [applyToArray(Math.min, pointsLong), applyToArray(Math.min, pointsLat)],
    [applyToArray(Math.max, pointsLong), applyToArray(Math.max, pointsLat)]
  ]
  // Use WebMercatorViewport to get center longitude/latitude and zoom
  const viewport = new WebMercatorViewport({ width: 600, height: 600 })
    // @ts-ignore
    .fitBounds(cornersLongLat, { padding: {top:150, bottom:200, left:100, right:150} }) 
  const { longitude, latitude, zoom } = viewport
  return { longitude, latitude, zoom }
}

const myMap = () => {

  const bounds = getBoundsForPoints(parkData.features);

  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    width: "100%",
    height: "600px",
    ...bounds
  });
  const [selectedPark, setSelectedPark] = useState(null);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactMapGL
        {...viewport}
        mapboxApiAccessToken="pk.eyJ1IjoiYmVubmtpbmd5IiwiYSI6ImNrY2ozMnJ5dzBrZ28ycnA1b2Vqb2I0bXgifQ.ZOaVtzsDQOrAovh9Orh13Q"
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
        onViewportChange={viewport => {
          setViewport(viewport);
        }}

      >
        {parkData.features.map(park => (
          <Marker
            key={park.properties.PARK_ID}
            latitude={park.geometry.coordinates[1]}
            longitude={park.geometry.coordinates[0]}
          >
            <button
              className="marker-btn"
              onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                setSelectedPark(park);
              }}
            >
              <img src={mapIcon} alt="Map Pointer Icon" />
            </button>
          </Marker>
        ))}
      </ReactMapGL>
      {selectedPark ? (
        <div>
          <h2>{selectedPark.properties.NAME}</h2>
          <p>{selectedPark.properties.DESCRIPTIO}</p>
          <button onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                setSelectedPark(null);
              }}>X</button>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default myMap;
```